# How to capture images and attach them to Cucumber Reports (Jenkins) using Selenium Hub, Node and Remote Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

Currently I'm triggering my automation tests in the cloud using a Ubuntu instance.

The Ubuntu instance has a Jenkins instance running and also Selenium Hub and Node. It seems the screenshot images dont get saved within the builds\3\cucumber-html-reports\embeddings on a ubuntu system however on a windows system this issue does not exist.

I have currently added the below logic to capture and attach images to the Jenkins Cucumber reports however currently the images are not getting attached to the reports:

```
@After
public void after(Scenario scenario) {
    if (scenario.isFailed()) {
        try {
            WebDriver augmentedDriver = new Augmenter().augment(getDriver());
            byte[] s = ((TakesScreenshot)augmentedDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
            scenario.embed(s, "image/png");
```

Example Report (Generated in Jenkins), please note the images are getting saved and attached to the reports when running the tests locally. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If this does not work then you may give a thought to below way of attaching screen shot to report on jenkins.

Hooks looks like below -

```
@After
    public void afterScenario(Scenario scenario){
        try{
            if(scenario.isFailed()){
                ExtentTestManager.addScreenShotsOnFailure();
    // More code goes here....
```

Method to capture image - please customize path as per your need.

```
public static void addScreenShotsOnFailure() {
    i = i + 1;
    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) DriverManager.getDriver()).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

    Date d = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E dd MMM HH:mm:ss z yyyy");  
    String strDate = formatter.format(d);
    screenshotName = strDate.replace(":", "_").replace(" ", "_") + "_"+i+".jpg";

    try {
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/target/extent-report/" + screenshotName));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the above, the above logic uses Extent reports, currently im looking for a way to add images to Cucumber reports.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have direct answer for ubuntu problem. But, try adding path of captured images to your cucumber report as html links.

```
@After
public void after(Scenario scenario){
   if (scenario.isFailed()) {
        try {
            WebDriver augmentedDriver = new Augmenter().augment(getDriver());
            File path = ((TakesScreenshot)augmentedDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            FileUtils.copyFile(path,new File(localRepoPath));
            String html = "<html><body><a href=\">" + localRepoPath + "\"> screenshot </a></body></html>";
            scenario.embed(html.getBytes(), "text/html");
       }catch(Exception e){
          // Do Something
       }
  }        
}
```