# Cucumber scenario.embed doesnt work on a ubuntu machine?

Tags: java, selenium, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

My code:

```
WebDriver augmentedDriver = new Augmenter().augment(getDriver());
final byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) augmentedDriver)
.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");
```

When attempting to take a snapshot on a Ubuntu machine, the above code doesn't work? (Code above works on a windows machine)

When I inspect the Cucumber folder report information is visible however the exception images are not not.

My Runner class:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

@CucumberOptions(features = { "classpath:features/" }, glue = {
        "stepDefinitions" }, monochrome = true, tags = {"@login"}, dryRun = false,
        plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber1", "json:target/cucumber1.json"})

public class MainRunner1 extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56360891/how-to-capture-images-and-attach-them-to-cucumber-reports-jenkins-using-seleni

Comment: @Bhuvanesh Mani I have narrowed the issue down; reasons for creating a different ticket, the comments listed in stackoverflow.com/questions/56360891/ have provided no resolution for the original issue.